# How to change the display field to use when use jdl?

Tags: jhipster

When use jhipster entity generator by console  a question like follow allows to change the display field on frontend:

> When you display this relationship with AngularJS, which field from
> 'user' do you want to use? (id)

It is possible to make the same with jdl?

> Edited

Ok, It appears that nobody has this problem, or maybe there aren't anybody in home?

So, I'm going to explain it. Let's suppose this scenario:

- Create two (or more) entities with relationship with the console.
- Choose a different field from id to manage the front-end.
- Test the project (it works fine).
- Export the model to jdl file
- Import the jdl file, with no changes, in another new project.
- Boom! The UI comes back to Id reference.

Is there any option to resolve it, or is this resolve in other tools like uml import? Future plans?

**Resolved**

Reading the documentation in detail, I've found a solution:

> "Declare the field you want to use to display a relationship in AngularJS.
>
> To do that you must add the field name between () after the injected field name."

Answer (score 2):

**Resolved**

Reading the documentation in detail, I've found a solution:

> "Declare the field you want to use to display a relationship in
>   AngularJS.
>
> To do that you must add the field name between () after the injected
>   field name."